# XPath match elements, which doesn't contain specified descendant

Tags: xml, xpath

I have a XML file with multiple level structure (it is a directory structure with files, thus there are `<directory name="...">` and `<file name="...">` elements)

and I want to select empty directories with XPath, but I don't know, how to select nodes, which doesn't have some descendants.
I can match the `ns:directory[not(ns:file)]` but it is only the first level of emtpy directories and I dont want to do anything like `ns:directory[not(ns:file)]|ns:directory[ns:directory[not(ns:file)]]|...`

Could someone please hint, how to do this?

Comment: If you search for "descendant" in the xpath spec you'll see that there is a `descendant::` _axis_ that will help you here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy.

```
//ns:directory[not(.//ns:file)]
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer above will exclude directories that only contain directories.  If that's what you want, fine.  If you're looking for directories that are completely empty, try this:

```
//ns:directory[not(ns:file|ns:directory)]
```